# Only first Reverse Proxy Virtual Host works

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am trying to redirect services running on localhost under various ports to a sub-path on a single port. For example http://127.0.0.100:5687/ to http://127.0.0.1/app/.

The issue I am having is that only the first Virtual Host block works. If I swap the 2 hosts only topmost/first host work. All other hosts return Not Found error.

Here are the apache directives in question:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app1.example.com
  #ServerAlias app1
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /app1 http://127.0.0.1:6687/
  ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://127.0.0.1:6687/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app2.example.com
  #ServerAlias app2
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /app2 http://127.0.0.1:7687/
  ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://127.0.0.1:7687/
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I not seeing here? Why does only the first Virtual Host work?

Answer (score 1):

None of your `VirtualHost` blocks matches `127.0.0.1`, so Apache takes the first block it finds.

Your virtualhosts are distinguished by the `ServerName`. If you want to reach both `/app1` and `/app2` with `127.0.0.1` you have to place both `ProxyPass` directives in the same `VirtualHost` block.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app1.example.com
  ServerAlias app2.example.com
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /app1 http://127.0.0.1:6687/
  ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://127.0.0.1:6687/
  ProxyPass /app2 http://127.0.0.1:7687/
  ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://127.0.0.1:7687/
</VirtualHost>
```

Or just use the `ServerName` instead in your http requests.

```
http://app1.example.com/app1/
http://app2.example.com/app2/
```

The `/app*` is redundant anyway, i'd just drop it and use `ProxyPass / http://...` with two VirtualHosts.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second option? An example maybe?

Comment: The second option is your current configuration.

Comment: Ok, but how would that work locally accessed from lets say http://192.168.0.100/app1? To clarify I want all of the following to point to a certain local app: app1/ (will modify /etc/hosts on client), http://[ip]/app1 (local network only) and http://app1.example.com/ (DNS will be configured).

Comment: The first option doesn't work either, same result as before, only the first ProxyPass path works while the second returns 404.